# Show that $\tan(3\pi/11)+4\sin(2\pi/11)=\sqrt{11}$ to 500 significant digits

Tags: trigonometry

Does anyone know how to prove that:

```
Tan[3 π/11] + 4 Sin[2 π/11] == Sqrt[11]
```

to 500 significant digits

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at `N` https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html

Comment: And also to `Equal` (or `==`) https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html

Comment: `Tan[3 Pi/11] + 4 Sin[2 Pi/11] == Sqrt[11] // FullSimplify` evaluates to `True` so they are equal to an arbitrarily large number of digits.

Comment: One can also use `RootReduce[]` to prove this.

Answer (score 4):

To "Prove" in Mathematica, one way might be

```
lhs = Tan[3 Pi/11] + 4 Sin[2 Pi/11];
rhs = Sqrt[11];
N[lhs - rhs, {Infinity, 500}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Accuracy[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FullSimplify[lhs - rhs]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]